# .getjson from external domain. Print from the Array

Tags: jsonp, getjson

I'm currently getting 2 arrays from the following get statement.

```
 $.getJSON("http://domain.com?callback=?", function(data){
  $("#results").html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I'm appending the results in a div with the id results.

All that is doing is just displaying the array. I need to pull certain objects from the array but I can't do that because I am just printing the whole array. How do I get specific information from that array?

Here is some of the data that is being appended to the DIV.

{"me":[{"player":{"high_score":110345,"rank":2}}],"all":[{"player":{"@score := s.score":110345,"avatar":"http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/195312_789328764_1121893995_q.jpg","guid":"FE4EC535-B74F-4B68-8F4D-2CA0EBC28FAF","name":"Charles Chase","rank":1,"score":110345}},

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the returned json data?

Comment: I added it to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure, it looks incomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the following is your returned JSON data

```
{    
    "me": [
                {
                    "player": {
                        "high_score": 110345,
                        "rank": 2
                    }
                }
            ],
            "all": [
                {
                    "player": {
                        "@score := s.score": 110345,
                        "avatar": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/195312_789328764_1121893995_q.jpg",
                        "guid": "FE4EC535-B74F-4B68-8F4D-2CA0EBC28FAF",
                        "name": "Charles Chase",
                        "rank": 1,
                        "score": 110345
                    }
                }
            ]
        };
```

You can use the following to grab the values from the JSON object

**CODE**

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.com?callback=?", function(data){
  alert(data.me[0].player.high_score);
  alert(data.all[0].player.name);
));
```

Note `me` and `all` is returned as array. I hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome. If I wanted to write the output on the page would I do: var test = (data.all[0].player.name); document.write(test);

Comment: I think you already have a div with id results. Just do it $("#results").html(data.all[0].player.name);